# Docker how can I mount /usr/local/etc/php/ folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker container I'm able to access below folder

```
docker exec -it lara_giftoff bash
root@4b8497edceab:/var/www/html# cd /usr/local/etc/php/
root@4b8497edceab:/usr/local/etc/php# ls
conf.d  php.ini-development  php.ini-production
```

Now when I'm trying to mount using volume , both local and docker container folder made empty !

```
lara_giftoff:
    container_name: lara_giftoff
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./lara_giftoff:/var/www/html
      - ./config/php:/usr/local/etc/php
    ports:
      - 2000:80
```

So I remove this - ./config/php:/usr/local/etc/php from volume , and add copy in
DockerFile like below

```
FROM php:8.1.0-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
# Mod Rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite
# Linux Library
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libmariadb-dev \
    unzip zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libsodium-dev
# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
# PHP Extension
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext intl pdo_mysql gd sodium bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

COPY ./config/php/ /usr/local/etc/php/    <-- here
```

When I'm trying to rebuild my image, I'm getting below error

```
=> ERROR [stage-0 8/8] COPY ./config/php/ /usr/local/etc/php/                                                   0.0s
------
 > [stage-0 8/8] COPY ./config/php/ /usr/local/etc/php/:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/config/php" not found: not found
ERROR: Service 'lara_giftoff' failed to build : Build failed
make[2]: *** [build] Error 1
make[1]: *** [setup] Error 2
make: *** [rebuild] Error 2
```

If I create a folder in my localhost like below , I'm not getting any error but after rebuild image it's always keeping empty.

[image]

How can I mount this /usr/local/etc/php/ to my project ./config/php directory ?

Comment: try instead of 
'COPY ./config/php/ /usr/local/etc/php/ '
to add
'RUN mkdir -r /usr/local/etc/php/'

Comment: @RyabchenkoAlexander I have tried by. RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/php/. do I require to change anything in volume ?

Answer (score 0):

mine worked, no issues , no deleting host files, put an html file in your current directory and try this

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  test:
    image: php:8.3-apache
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```